# jQueryUI Tabs - force click on tab via POST variable

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I wish to be able to open page on a specific tab by sending a message via GET variable. I was thinking something like:

```
http://mydomain/mytimecards.php?tab=vte
```

Here is the code for the jQuery tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#mytimecards">Submit Time Cards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#timecardReports" id="vte">View Time Entries</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="mytimecards">
    etc ....
```

Is it possible to force the page to display the 2nd tab (#timecardReports) instead of the first ONLY IF ?tab=vte is received as a GET (or better yet POST) variable?

Comment: I don't know this part of jquery, but it should have an atribute for active tab, which you could change depending on the get variable

Comment: You're unable to have the fragment identifier `#timecardReports` in the URL when you call the page? Seems like the same logic that would add `tab=vte` to the URL could add the fragment identifier.

Comment: observe the js console. try clicking each tabs and see what class it adds and removes. then just add the class depending on the get variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the plugin you are using allows you to set an active tab on load, you could do something like:

```
<li><a href="#timecardReports" id="vte" <? if(isset($_GET['tab']) && $_GET['tab'] == 'vte'){ echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>View Time Entries</a></li>
```

Replacing `class="active"` with whatever the plugin requires you to set.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys, Ben and itachi were onto the right solution.  This worked:

```
http://mydomain.com/mytimecards.php?tab=vte#timecardReports
```

I found this by using firebug and watching what changed as the tabs were clicked. Thanks itachi.

Ben's suggestion enabled me to test for this condition and set it on page load.

Credit to them both.